# Multiple objects in one Fluid form

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

I need to put two objects in one form with fluid.
The background is: I have a userDomain and a ordering object. Both are not persistent. I want to send these two objects to an action without making one of them persistent. The userDomain object is handled by the form, the other is assigned to the view. If I add the ordering object to the arguments section in the Form, Typo3 throws me this error:

```
Oops, an error occurred!

Could not serialize Domain Object Whmcs\Registration\Domain\Model\Ordering. It is neither an Entity with identity properties set, nor a Value Object.

More information regarding this error might be available online.
```

This is because the object is non-persistent and does not have any ID.

So the question is, how I do pass these two objects to the next action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to pass non persistent objects between multiple actions, I would suggest that you store the objects serialized in a TYPO3 session variable. Doing so, you can restore the objects in the target action.

Below you find a working example which can also be found [here](https://github.com/derhansen/extbase_validation_new_pm/blob/master/Classes/Controller/MultipleStepsController.php).

```
<?php
namespace derhansen\ValidationExamplesNew\Controller;

/***************************************************************
 *  Copyright notice
 *
 *  (c) 2013 Torben Hansen <derhansen@gmail.com>
 *
 *  All rights reserved
 *
 *  This script is part of the TYPO3 project. The TYPO3 project is
 *  free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 *  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 *  the Free Software Foundation; either version 3 of the License, or
 *  (at your option) any later version.
 *
 *  The GNU General Public License can be found at
 *  http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html.
 *
 *  This script is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 *  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 *  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 *  GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 *  This copyright notice MUST APPEAR in all copies of the script!
 ***************************************************************/

/**
 * Multiple Steps Controller
 *
 * @package validation_examples_new
 * @license http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html GNU General Public License, version 3 or later
 *
 */
class MultipleStepsController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController {

    /**
     * addressdataRepository
     *
     * @var \derhansen\ValidationExamplesNew\Domain\Repository\AddressdataRepository
     * @inject
     */
    protected $addressdataRepository;

    /**
     * API Service
     *
     * @var \derhansen\ValidationExamplesNew\Service\ExternalApiService
     * @inject
     */
    protected $apiService;

    /**
     * Step1
     *
     * @param \derhansen\ValidationExamplesNew\Domain\Model\Step1Data $step1data
     * @dontvalidate $step1data
     */
    public function step1Action(\derhansen\ValidationExamplesNew\Domain\Model\Step1Data $step1data = NULL) {
        /* Check if step1data is available in session */
        if ($GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->getKey('ses', 'step1data') && $step1data == NULL) {
            $step1data = unserialize($GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->getKey('ses', 'step1data'));
        }

        $this->view->assign('step1data', $step1data);
    }

    /**
     * Step1 redirect action
     *
     * @param \derhansen\ValidationExamplesNew\Domain\Model\Step1Data $step1data
     */
    public function step1redirectAction(\derhansen\ValidationExamplesNew\Domain\Model\Step1Data $step1data) {
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setKey('ses', 'step1data', serialize($step1data));
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->storeSessionData();

        $this->redirect('step2');
    }

    /**
     * Step2
     *
     * @param \derhansen\ValidationExamplesNew\Domain\Model\Step2Data $step2data
     * @dontvalidate $step2data
     */
    public function step2Action(\derhansen\ValidationExamplesNew\Domain\Model\Step2Data $step2data = NULL) {
        /* Check if step2data is available in session */
        if ($GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->getKey('ses', 'step2data') && $step2data == NULL) {
            $step2data = unserialize($GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->getKey('ses', 'step2data'));
        }

        /* Set external validations errors if available */
        $this->setApiValidationErrors('step2');

        $this->view->assign('step2data', $step2data);
    }

    /**
     * Step2 redirect action
     *
     * @param \derhansen\ValidationExamplesNew\Domain\Model\Step2Data $step2data
     */
    public function step2redirectAction(\derhansen\ValidationExamplesNew\Domain\Model\Step2Data $step2data) {
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setKey('ses', 'step2data', serialize($step2data));
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->storeSessionData();

        $this->redirect('step3');
    }


    /**
     * Step3
     *
     * @param \derhansen\ValidationExamplesNew\Domain\Model\Step3Data $step3data
     * @dontvalidate $step3data
     */
    public function step3Action(\derhansen\ValidationExamplesNew\Domain\Model\Step3Data $step3data = NULL) {
        /* Check if step3data is available in session */
        if ($GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->getKey('ses', 'step3data') && $step3data == NULL) {
            $step3data = unserialize($GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->getKey('ses', 'step3data'));
        }

        /* Set external validations errors if available */
        $this->setApiValidationErrors('step3');

        $this->view->assign('step3data', $step3data);
    }

    /**
     * Step3 redirect action
     *
     * @param \derhansen\ValidationExamplesNew\Domain\Model\Step3Data $step3data
     */
    public function step3redirectAction(\derhansen\ValidationExamplesNew\Domain\Model\Step3Data $step3data) {
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setKey('ses', 'step3data', serialize($step3data));
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->storeSessionData();

        $this->redirect('create');
    }

    /**
     * Create Action
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function createAction() {
        $addressdata = $this->getAddressdataFromSession();

        /* get validation results from API */
        $apiresults = $this->apiService->validateMultipleSteps($addressdata);
        if (count($apiresults) > 0) {
            /* Save results to a session variable */
            $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setKey('ses', 'apiresults', $apiresults);
            $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->storeSessionData();

            /* Redirect to step with validation errors */
            if (array_key_exists('step2', $apiresults)) {
                $this->redirect('step2');
            }
            if (array_key_exists('step3', $apiresults)) {
                $this->redirect('step3');
            }
        }

        $this->addressdataRepository->add($addressdata);
        $this->cleanUpSessionData();

        $this->view->assign('message', 'Addressdata has been created');
    }

    /**
     * Collects the addressdata from the multiple steps form stored in session variables
     * and returns an addressdata object.
     *
     * @return \derhansen\ValidationExamplesNew\Domain\Model\Addressdata
     */
    protected function getAddressdataFromSession() {
        /** @var \derhansen\ValidationExamplesNew\Domain\Model\Step1Data $step1data */
        $step1data = unserialize($GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->getKey('ses', 'step1data'));

        /** @var \derhansen\ValidationExamplesNew\Domain\Model\Step2Data $step2data */
        $step2data = unserialize($GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->getKey('ses', 'step2data'));

        /** @var \derhansen\ValidationExamplesNew\Domain\Model\Step3Data $step3data */
        $step3data = unserialize($GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->getKey('ses', 'step3data'));

        /** @var \derhansen\ValidationExamplesNew\Domain\Model\Addressdata $addressData */
        $addressData = $this->objectManager->get('derhansen\ValidationExamplesNew\Domain\Model\Addressdata');
        $addressData->setFirstname($step1data->getFirstname());
        $addressData->setLastname($step1data->getLastname());
        $addressData->setStreet($step2data->getStreet());
        $addressData->setStreetnr($step2data->getStreetnr());
        $addressData->setZip($step3data->getZip());
        $addressData->setCity($step3data->getCity());

        return $addressData;
    }

    /**
     * Removes all session variables from the multiple steps form
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function cleanUpSessionData() {
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setKey('ses', 'step1data', '');
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setKey('ses', 'step2data', '');
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setKey('ses', 'step3data', '');
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setKey('ses', 'apiresults', '');
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->storeSessionData();
    }

    /**
     * Sets validation errors for fields in the given step
     *
     * @param string $step The step
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setApiValidationErrors($step) {
        $apiresults = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->getKey('ses', 'apiresults');
        if (array_key_exists($step, $apiresults)) {
            /* Set Form Errors manually  - get results from property mapper and add new errors */
            $result = $this->getControllerContext()->getRequest()->getOriginalRequestMappingResults();

            /* Add validation errors */
            foreach ($apiresults[$step] as $key => $value) {
                $error = $this->objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Validation\Error',
                    $apiresults[$step][$key], time());
                $result->forProperty($step . 'data.' . $key)->addError($error);
            }
            $this->getControllerContext()->getRequest()->setOriginalRequestMappingResults($result);
        }
    }

}
?>
```

This example is part of a multiple step form validation example, but uses TYPO3 session variables in order to store the input of each form step.